# Tokenize the text depending on some specific rules. Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tokenize

I am writing a program which will tokenize the input text depending upon some specific rules. I am using C++ for this.

**Rules**

```
Letter 'a' should be converted to token 'V-A'
Letter 'p' should be converted to token 'C-PA'
Letter 'pp' should be converted to token 'C-PPA'
Letter 'u' should be converted to token 'V-U'
```

This is just a sample and in real time I have around 500+ rules like this. If I am providing input as '*appu*', it should tokenize like '*V-A + C-PPA + V-U*'. I have implemented an algorithm for doing this and wanted to make sure that I am doing the right thing.

**Algorithm**

All rules will be kept in a XML file with the corresponding mapping to the token. Something like

```
<rules>
  <rule pattern="a" token="V-A" />
  <rule pattern="p" token="C-PA" />
  <rule pattern="pp" token="C-PPA" />
  <rule pattern="u" token="V-U" />
</rules>
```

1 - When the application starts, read this xml file and keep the values in a '*std::map*'. This will be available until the end of the application(singleton pattern implementation).

2 - Iterate the input text characters. For each character, look for a match. If found, become more greedy and look for more matches by taking the next characters from the input text. Do this until we are getting a no match. So for the input text '*appu*', first look for a match for '*a*'. If found, try to get more match by taking the next character from the input text. So it will try to match '*ap*' and found no matches. So it just returns.

3 - Replace the letter 'a' from input text as we got a token for it.

4 - Repeat step 2 and 3 with the remaining characters in the input text.

Here is a more simple explanation of the steps

```
input-text = 'appu'
tokens-generated=''

// First iteration
character-to-match = 'a'
pattern-found = true

// since pattern found, going recursive and check for more matches
character-to-match = 'ap'
pattern-found = false

tokens-generated = 'V-A'

// since no match found for 'ap', taking the first success and replacing it from input text
input-text = 'ppu'

// second iteration
character-to-match = 'p'
pattern-found = true

// since pattern found, going recursive and check for more matches
character-to-match = 'pp'
pattern-found = true

// since pattern found, going recursive and check for more matches
character-to-match = 'ppu'
pattern-found = false

tokens-generated = 'V-A + C-PPA'

// since no match found for 'ppu', taking the first success and replacing it from input text
input-text = 'u'

// third iteration
character-to-match = 'u'
pattern-found = true

tokens-generated = 'V-A + C-PPA + V-U'  // we'r done!
```

**Questions**

1 - Is this algorithm looks fine for this problem or is there a better way to address this problem?

2 - If this is the right method, std::map is a good choice here? Or do I need to create my own key/value container?

3 - Is there a library available which can tokenize string like the above?

Any help would be appreciated

:)

Comment: Do you take into account the case where you have a long match but not a short one? For example, assume that you don't have the 'p' pattern. Will your algorithm go on to find the 'pp' pattern? Parsing 'p' won't give a direct match, but you should nevertheless continue the recursion.

Comment: Yes. It will continue the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're going through all of the tokens in your map looking for matches? You might as well use a list or array, there; it's going to be an inefficient search regardless.

A much more efficient way of finding just the tokens suitable for starting or continuing a match would be to store them as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). A lookup of a letter there would give you a sub-trie which contains only the tokens which have that letter as the first letter, and then you just continue searching downward as far as you can go.

---

Edit: let me explain this a little further.

First, I should explain that I'm not familiar with these the C++ `std::map`, beyond the name, which makes this a perfect example of why one learns the theory of this stuff as well as than details of particular libraries in particular programming languages: unless that library is badly misusing the name "map" (which is rather unlikely), the name itself tells me a lot about the characteristics of the data structure. I know, for example, that there's going to be a function that, given a single key and the map, will very efficiently search for and return the value associated with that key, and that there's also likely a function that will give you a list/array/whatever of all of the keys, which you could search yourself using your own code.

My interpretation of your data structure is that you have a map where the keys are what you call a pattern, those being a list (or array, or something of that nature) of characters, and the values are tokens. Thus, you can, given a full pattern, quickly find the token associated with it.

Unfortunately, while such a map is a good match to converting your XML input format to a internal data structure, it's not a good match to the searches you need to do. Note that you're not looking up entire patterns, but the first character of a pattern, producing a set of possible tokens, followed by a lookup of the second character of a pattern *from within the set of patterns produced by that first lookup*, and so on.

So what you really need is not a single map, but maps of maps of maps, each keyed by a single character. A lookup of "p" on the top level should give you a new map, with two keys: `p`, producing the `C-PPA` token, and "anything else", producing the `C-PA` token. This is effectively a trie data structure.

Does this make sense?

It may help if you start out by writing the parsing code first, in this manner: imagine someone else will write the functions to do the lookups you need, and he's a really good programmer and can do pretty much any magic that you want. Writing the parsing code, concentrate on making that as simple and clean as possible, creating whatever interface using these arbitrary functions you need (while not getting trivial and replacing the whole thing with one function!). Now you can look at the lookup functions you ended up with, and that tells you how you need to access your data structure, which will lead you to the type of data structure you need. Once you've figured that out, you can then work out how to load it up.

Comment: AFAIk, std::map will use a logarithmic lookup rather than searching sequentially. I am not sure how sequential containers like list or array benefits here. Can you please explain? "trie" is new to me and I will take a look at that. Thanks

Comment: I have found a "trie" library on http://wikipedia-clustering.speedblue.org/trie.php. Do you have any idea about this? Is that a good one?

Answer (score 1):

1. This method will work - I'm not sure that it is efficient, but it should work.
2. I would use the standard std::map rather than your own system.
3. There are tools like `lex` (or `flex`) that can be used for this.  The issue would be whether you can regenerate the lexical analyzer that it would construct when the XML specification changes.  If the XML specification does not change often, you may be able to use tools such as `lex` to do the scanning and mapping more easily.  If the XML specification can change at the whim of those using the program, then `lex` is probably less appropriate.

There are some caveats - notably that both `lex` and `flex` generate C code, rather than C++.

I would also consider looking at pattern matching technology - the sort of stuff that `egrep` in particular uses.  This has the merit of being something that can be handled at runtime (because `egrep` does it all the time).  Or you could go for a scripting language - Perl, Python, ...  Or you could consider something like PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) library.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to hear that this method will work. My XML changes frequently as new rules may be added(not by user). I will check lex or flex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex (perhaps the boost::regex library). If all of the patterns are just strings of letters, a regex like "(a|p|pp|u)" would find a greedy match. So:

1. Run a regex_search using the above pattern to locate the next match
2. Plug the match-text into your std::map to get the replace-text.
3. Print the non-matched consumed input and replace-text to your output, then repeat 1 on the remaining input.

And done.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, if you're going to use the boost library, there's always the Boost tokenizer library -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I have already checked boost tokenizer library. But that doesn't looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem a bit complicated, but the most efficient way to do that is to use a graph to represent a state-chart. At first, i thought [boost.statechart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html) would help, but i figured it wasn't really appropriate. This method can be more efficient that using a simple std::map IF there are many rules, the number of possible characters is limited and the length of the text to read is quite high.

So anyway, using a simple graph :

0) create graph with "start" vertex

1) read xml configuration file and create vertices when needed (transition from one "set of characters" (eg "pp") to an additional one (eg "ppa")). Inside each vertex, store a transition table to the next vertices. If "key text" is complete, mark vertex as final and store the resulting text

2) now read text and interpret it using the graph. Start at the "start" vertex. ( * ) Use table to interpret one character and to jump to new vertex. If no new vertex has been selected, an error can be issued. Otherwise, if new vertex is final, print the resulting text and jump back to start vertex. Go back to (*) until there is no more text to interpret.

You could use [boost.graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) to represent the graph, but i think it is overly complex for what you need. Make your own custom representation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are talking about the "trie" style graph. I am checking that currently. Thanks for the suggestion,